# How to save data , in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, save, nsuserdefaults

I am developing an application where the user creates an event which has 3 fields:

*Category , name , event.*   After the user gives his entry , i have a save button that will save his data for future reference. Then when he opens the app again the data will be shown in a table View.

How exactly do i "save" data on iOS ? I know about the NSUserDefaults , but i am pretty sure this is not the way for this example.

**What i ve done so far :**

I created a "Note" class with Category , name , event.

The code for my save button looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    //creating a new "note" object
    Note *newNote = [[Note alloc]init];

    newNote.category = categoryField.text;
    newNote.name = nameField.text;
    newNote.event = eventField.text;

    // do whatever you do to fill the object with data

    NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newNote];

    /*
     Now we create the path to the documents directory for your app
     */

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    /*
     Here we append a unique filename for this object, in this case, 'Note'
     */

    NSString* filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Note"];

    /*
     Finally, let's write the data to our file
     */

    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    /*
     We're done!
     */
}
```

Is this the correct way to save an event? How can i retrieve now what i wrote ?

Secondly if i run this code again i ll overwrite data , or create new entry?

I would like to see how i can make a new entry every time.

Also i would like to delete an event from the table that i am presenting them , so i would like to see how the delete would work.

My "Note" object looks like that:

```
@interface Note : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *category;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *event;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *category;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *event;

@end
```

Comment: either learn core data or stick to `NSUSerDefaults` for now.

Comment: So the way i am using to store it is wrong?

Comment: You have many options, saving as plist, sqlite, core data. If it's very simple you can use plist. NSUserDefaults is again a plist, but it's not recommended to use for this purpose.

Comment: the way you are doing requires more labour which will probably lead to more errors and should be the last way for storing things like simple. such data should go into database

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo Stick with your own code. It is better than what the answers provide (assuming you properly implemented the NSCoding methods). Nothing wrong with using NSCoding. Instead of the note you could archive an NSMutableArray instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//Note.h 

#define kNoteCategory  @"Category"
#define kNoteName      @"Name"
#define kNoteEvent     @"Event"

@interface Note : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *event;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

+ (NSArray *)savedNotes;
- (void)save;
```

//Note.m file

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.category = dictionary[kNoteCategory];
        self.name = dictionary[kNoteName];
        self.event = dictionary[kNoteEvent];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (NSString *)userNotesDocumentPath
{
    NSString *documentsPath  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserNotes.plist"];

    return documentsPath;

}

+ (NSArray *)savedNotes
{
    NSString *documentsPath = [self userNotesDocumentPath];
    NSArray *savedNotes = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:documentsPath];
    NSMutableArray *savedUserNotes = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in savedNotes) {
        Note *note = [[Note alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
        [savedUserNotes addObject:note];
    }

    return savedUserNotes;

}

- (NSDictionary *)userNoteDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    if (self.category) {
        dict[kNoteCategory] = self.category;
    }
    if (self.name) {
        dict[kNoteName] = self.name;
    }
    if (self.event) {
        dict[kNoteEvent] = self.event;
    }

    return dict;
}

- (void)saveUserNotesToPlist:(NSArray *)userNotes
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableUserNotes = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (Note *note in userNotes) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [note userNoteDictionary];
        [mutableUserNotes addObject:dict];
    }
    NSString *documentsPath  = [Note userNotesDocumentPath];
    [mutableUserNotes writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Save

- (void)save
{
    NSMutableArray *savedNotes = [[Note savedNotes] mutableCopy];
    [savedNotes addObject:self];
    [self saveUserNotesToPlist:savedNotes];
}
```

Save a note by

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    //creating a new "note" object
    Note *newNote = [[Note alloc]init];

    newNote.category = categoryField.text;
    newNote.name = nameField.text;
    newNote.event = eventField.text;

    //Saves the note to plist
    [newNote save];

    //To get all saved notes
    NSArray *savedNotes = [Note savedNotes];
}
```

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestPlistWriter_V2.1.zip)

Comment: I get some errors in the note.m class. Are you sure is complete? In the beginning shouldnt have @ implementation @ end or something? I get in the end of the file that an @end is missing , in the beggining of the file also a strange error..

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo What is the error you are getting. I intentionally didn't include trivial code.

Comment: ok ok i fixed it. i am testing it right now. i ll provide feedback in a bit. if it works question is yours.. in the meanwhile would be nice to provide some code on how to delete a dictionary from the array.

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo I have put the source code i made earlier in my answer.

Comment: I ran the code. The truth is i am a bit confused. The NSArray *savedNotes whats exactly does it have inside? I suppose is an array with dictionaries? If yes how can i print it to see the values inside? Also how can i refer to a dictionary (that means a note) inside this array? i tried to print the array but i only got the category printed. nothing else. I expected a dictionary with all the values. But at least it doesnt overwrite. Everytime it prints me the previous category too

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo I have updated the source to include editing. With a typical work flow of list notes and deleting the items from tableView with tableView animation.

Comment: Anupdas thank you really a lot for your source code. The last 2 days i am trying to transform it though , to work with .nib files but i am getting errors. Would it be possible to update the code working with nibs? The storyboards confuse me really a lot.

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo Glad to know that it helped you. I think the confusion of storyboard is just a matter of getting used to. Going forward it would be good if you get familiar with that. I'm attaching an XIB version of the [source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestPlistWriter_V2.2.zip)

Comment: Just one last question. When i asked you for the nib files , i was hoping to see how u use the editable table view in your nib file. In your example you create it programatically by subclassing the UITableViewController. Now if i want to make the tableView transparent so i can put a background image on it , or i want to put it in a certain position into the canvas i guess is more difficult to do that programmatically right? Do you know any tutorial that i could see more about this? Or should i search how to do it with .nib? Seems easier to change position , attributes , etc , with the builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSKeyedUnArchiver to retrieve the data. It will over write if you try to write in the same file path

Answer (score 0):

Look, I am giving you the General Idea, you can use this code according to your requirement.

1) Get the "Path" of `yourPlist.plist` file :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlist.plist"];
```

2) Insert data into the yourPlist :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:categoryField.text forKey:@"Category"];
[dict setValue:nameField.text forKey:@"Name"];
[dict setValue:eventField.text forKey:@"Event"];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr addObject:dict];

[arr writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
```

3) Retrieve data from the yourPlist :

```
NSMutableArray *savedStock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
for (NSDictionary *dict in savedStock) {
     NSLog(@"my Note : %@",dict);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Could you provide me how to save an object like "Note" (see updated question) and how to retrieve it . Also how not to overwrite the data.

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo : Check my Code again.

Comment: I ll accept your answer , if you can enlighten me where is the part that the Notes are saved one after another and not overwritten. I cant see how i could retrieve 5 different Notes with this code. Is the objectAtIndex:number , the position of the Note? So if i put there 1 , 2 , 3 i get the next Notes? If yes how do i do know the number of the Notes that are saved there so i can retrieve them all correctly?

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo : `[arr addObject:dict];` is the part that will "Add" new Note to the Array , not "Overwrite". Each `NSMutableDictionary` is your "Single" Note.

Comment: So if i understand well now to retrieve all the notes the only thing i have to do is to see whats the size of newDict and then newDict = [savedStock objectAtIndex:0]; here i use 1 2 3 4 till the size-1 to get all the notes? Also this line: NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  do i always leave it like this or i have to make 1 2 3 for every new note? Finally if u can provide me the delete method of the Note please.

Comment: @LolaEnaMilo : There is one more way. Check in My Answer.

Comment: Ok i see it now. Now looks good. So i always use this line : NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  as it is and never change the number there?

Comment: Thank you very much @Vin. I accepted the answer. IF you have some time , you could also show us the delete method for one of the notes.How do u delete them according to their position?

Comment: You can use :`[arr removeObjectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I am trying out your code and the last NSLog prints me only the last "note".. it seems that they overwrite each time... ?

Comment: Simply write the code for "alloc" and "init" of arr and dict in viewDidLoad method , don't write in your save method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use core data to save all your data and delete it when you want. The code above always create new object of Note class so every time new data you have but when you will try to write with the same name "Note". It always overwrite the old data.

Answer (score 0):

All are correct besides that you can use Sqlite to save the data locally with your application.

This is just a file but accepts all standard sql statements.

This is also one way to save the data locally..

Comment: I am looking at it now. Looks very very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For saving data via NSUserDefaults I'm using [GVUserDefaults](https://github.com/gangverk/GVUserDefaults)

### Usage

Create a category on GVUserDefaults, add some properties in the .h file and make them @dynamic in the .m file.

```
// .h
@interface GVUserDefaults (Properties)
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSNumber *userId;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger integerValue;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL boolValue;
@property (nonatomic) float floatValue;
@end
```

---

```
// .m
@implementation GVUserDefaults (Properties)
@dynamic userName;
@dynamic userId;
@dynamic integerValue;
@dynamic boolValue;
@dynamic floatValue;
@end
```

Now, instead of using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"]`, you can simply use `[GVUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].userName`.

You can even save defaults by setting the property:

```
[GVUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].userName = @"myusername";
```