# Saving a dynamic tableview's textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I keep posting about this same issue but I can't seem to get the answer and I've easily spent 30+ hours trying to figure it out. I will keep it as simple as possible. I have a dynamic tableview that adds custom cells when the "+" button is pressed. Each cell has 6 textFields. My problem now is that I save the textFields for one cell and it loads the same thing for every other cell. (by the way please just disregard the dynamic tableview reuse function)

Here is my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"expandingCell";

    ExpandingCell *cell = (ExpandingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExpandingCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Here is my code for the cells class: ExpandingCell.m

```
- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
    NSString *saveString = Date.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *saveString1 = Course.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults1 setObject:saveString1 forKey:@"saveString1"];
    [defaults1 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString2 = Score.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults2 setObject:saveString2 forKey:@"saveString2"];
    [defaults2 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString3 = Par.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults3 setObject:saveString3 forKey:@"saveString3"];
    [defaults3 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString4 = Putts.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults4 setObject:saveString4 forKey:@"saveString4"];
    [defaults4 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString5 = GIR.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults5 setObject:saveString5 forKey:@"saveString5"];
    [defaults5 synchronize];

}

- (IBAction)Load:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [Date setText:loadString];
    [DateLabel setText:loadString];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString1 = [defaults1 objectForKey:@"saveString1"];
    [Course setText:loadString1];
    [CourseLabel setText:loadString1];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString2 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"saveString2"];
    [Score setText:loadString2];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString3 = [defaults3 objectForKey:@"saveString3"];
    [Par setText:loadString3];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString4 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"saveString4"];
    [Putts setText:loadString4];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString5 = [defaults5 objectForKey:@"saveString5"];
    [GIR setText:loadString5];
}



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Please someone help its for a school project and I've desperately been trying to finish it before the deadline but I'm just totally lost on how to do this

Comment: You most likely have all the cells contents pointing to the same data.

Comment: BTW, variables by convention begin with a lowercase letter, classes with an uppercase letter. Well known acronyms excepted. Also there is no red to create individual `NSUserDefaults` variables. Take doe time to study Objective-C programming. Understand every line you write--and why.

Comment: @Zaph Sorry I've had to teach myself the language on my own for a high school class and the iOS developer book is very boring so my only other option is to follow tutorials on how to complete individual tasks. I guess I didn't get the best education on the language :D

Comment: Yep, most computer books are boring,  I have read a lot of them. But tutorials don't tell you why in many cases. You have to learn "C" and Objective-C and books and Apple documents are the way to go. I still read boring computer books regularly and I have been doing this for 40+ years. Try to read a little each night, even if it is only 1/2 hour. Start with very simple programs, that is where I started, one very small program I kept growing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ExpandingCell` implement `prepareForReuse` method and clear the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do the cells get reset immediately? Because if not, it seems like Zaph is correct that they all seem to be pointing to the same data. What you should do is create some kind of array or plist where you can store data for each cell rather than allocate and initialize data pointing to the same defaults. There is no way, afaik, that your cells can differentiate. Everytime you perform a load/save action, your data is written to the same place.

```
NSString *saveString = Date.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

^ You overwrite the value for key `saveString` each time, thats why when it is reloaded, you load the saved value. What you can do is do something along the lines of:

```
[defaults setObject:saveString forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveString%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];
```

This will ensure that a set of unique keys exist for each row, you can change out the row value for any other method of uniquely identifying a cell. perhaps you can try this:

```
[defaults setObject:saveString forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveString1%@",nameOfGolfer]];
```

What would be better is to create an NSDictionary, and inserting an organized array of the date, course, putt # and all that jazz.

This way, each key for the NSDictionary would contain an array, and the key for each array would be a golfer name or course name or something. You just need to add one level higher of organizing your data and it will work.

EDIT1:
If you did that, then you would only have one object for the key `saveString`. A little noob to noob crashcourse of dictionaries and arrays. Basically NSUserDefault is really just an NSDictionary that can assign ONLY ONE (NS) object/value/number/anything to ONE key. A normal NSDictionary can not have objects as properties, but can have multiple values for ONE key. So you could add a NSString objet and then reference it with the key `@"stringCatogory1"`, but there can only be one object for that key.

I think the NSUserDefaults is just a tool that Apple provided by combining an array and dictionary to let people make data persistent without creating their own custom framework for trying to save volatile data manually. You could basically just create a plist and manage it with an nsdictionary object everytime you wanted to change a value, essentially [creating your own custom nsuserdefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291086/saving-ios-data-to-plist).

for example

```
[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[defaults setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastname"];
[defaults synchronize]; //overwrites previous values saved from previous synch
```

Comment: I understand that I'm saving over the same data, so say I replaced [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"]; with [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"saveString1%ld",nameOfGolfer]];  I'm confused as to how that would solve the problem. Do I need to so something else like create an array for each separate textfield for each cell?

Comment: putting indexPath.row does not work it just gives an error and putting the 1%ld or 1%@ doesn't work when I try to load the program

Comment: can you show me the specific error it is giving you? The code works when I try it, here is a literal snippet from mine: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]`

Comment: Noob mistake just didn't create NSIndexPath in the header file. So when I use that line of code in replacement of [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"]; and then replace the load objectForKey with %ld then it doesnt load anything